# Typecast failed for iteration HashMap, expected object

Tags: java

I want to iterate over my hashmap, but an error occurs when writing a loop

```
Incompatible types. Found: 'java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>', required: 'java.lang.Object'
```

How can I fix it? Here is the whole code:

```
public static void writeToFile(HashMap averageTime) {
        try {
            File file = new File("newfile.txt");
            if (!file.exists())
                file.createNewFile();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : averageTime.entrySet()) {
                pw.println("IP: " + entry.getKey() + "AverageTime: " + entry.getValue());
            }
```

Comment: Why is `writeToFile` taking a `HashMap` instead of a `Map`, and why is it a raw type? It seems to me it should be declared as `writeToFile(Map<String, Integer> averageTime)` which would fix your problem. Don't use raw types; always specify the type parameters of generic types (except on the right hand side when creating them, when you can abbreviate them as `<>`, using the "diamond syntax"). And prefer interfaces over concrete types for parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Your Map is <String, Object>. So if You want to print the time you can do a simple Object.toString().
If You want to save the time as an Integer you need to cast From Object to Integer.

```
public static void writeToFile(HashMap averageTime) {
    try {
        File file = new File("newfile.txt");
        if (!file.exists())
            file.createNewFile();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : averageTime.entrySet()) {
            pw.println("IP: " + entry.getKey() + "AverageTime: " + entry.getValue().toString());
        }
```